# For any solutions $\phi_1(t)$ and $\phi_2(t)$ of $y''+py'+qy=f(t)$ we have $\lim_{t\to\infty}[\phi_1(t)-\phi_2(t)]=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I prove this statement?

If $p$ and $q$ are positive constants and $f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, show that for any solutions $\phi_1(t)$ and $\phi_2(t)$ of $y''+py'+qy=f(t)$ we have
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}[\phi_1(t)-\phi_2(t)]=0.$$

Comment: By linearity you can assume that $f = 0$ and $\phi_2 = 0$. Because p and q are constant you can solve explicitly this equation. The real exponential factor decreases to 0 because p is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

As

$$
\cases{
\phi_1''+p\phi_1'+q\phi_1 = f\\
\phi_2''+p\phi_2'+q\phi_2 = f
}\Rightarrow (\phi''_2-\phi''_1)+p(\phi'_2-\phi'_1)+q(\phi_2-\phi_1)=0
$$

now calling $\psi =\phi_2-\phi_1$ the ODE $\psi''+p\psi'+q\psi=0$ has as differential operator $s^2+ps+q = (s+p/2+\sqrt{p^2-4q}/2) (s+p/2-\sqrt{p^2-4q}/2)$ so the real component of both roots is negative and the solution is exponentially decreasing with time.

Comment: I didn't get how the limit is going to zero. =(

Comment: The solution is $\psi(t) = e^{-\frac 12 p t}\left(c_1 e^{-\sqrt{p^2-4q}\frac t2} +c_2e^{\sqrt{p^2-4q}\frac t2 }\right)$

Comment: Hey @Cesareo, I was thinking: why is this solution going to zero? I can't show this using the limit.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{p^2-\epsilon}=p-\frac{\epsilon}{2p}+O(\epsilon^2)$ then in the less favorable case we have $-p+\sqrt{p^2-\epsilon}\approx -\frac{\epsilon}{2p}$ and the exponential should be $e^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2p} t}$ so as the imaginary component is associated to a sinusoidal function, we have $|\psi(t)|\le e^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2p} t}$.

Comment: Ok! Thanks.  =) .